# PHP err if mysql command gives a result

Tags: php

I have this query

```
 $DB->query("SELECT id FROM tfilter WHERE '". $Properties['Title'] ."' LIKE CONCAT('%', filter, '%')");
```

I need it to do so that the scrip dies if it gets a result, right now i have this :

```
    if($DB->record_count() != 0) {
    $Err = '<b>This cant be uploaded</b>';
    include(SERVER_ROOT . '/sections/upload/upload.php');
    die();

if($DB->record_count() != 0) {
```

Should this be something els? Because it dosnt die, even though i KNOW its got a result

This query looks like this in the phpscript. Its part of a bigger site

```
$DB->query("SELECT id FROM tfilter WHERE '". $Properties['Title'] ."' LIKE CONCAT('%', filter, '%')");
 if($DB->record_count() != 0) {
 $Err = '<b>This cant be uploaded</b>';
 include(SERVER_ROOT . '/sections/upload/upload.php');
 die();

 $Properties['Title'] = String from the upload script that contains the titel.
 $DB is the call til mysql
 filter = the row in mysql
 tfilter = the database name
```

WHAT DO I NEED:

I need the php to search the the tabel TFILTER in the row FILTER for matches to $Properties['Title'] and if it finds any then DIE. If the string: The.White.Tiger. exist in FILTER row, og the $Properties['Title'] contains The.White.Tiger.In.The.Yard, the the php should DIE.

Comment: WTF? the _field_ in the where clause is variable, but the value is a constant? you could end up with a query like `SELECT id FROM filter WHERE id LIKE CONCAT('%', filter, '%')`... which is non-sense (invalid query)

Comment: I testet the query in phpmyadmin, it works and it finds only the results it need to, the problem is the  if($DB->record_count() != 0) { dosnt work. It dosnt die on the one result i know it gets

Comment: All well and good that the query worked on PHPMyAdmin, but I doubt the query looked quite like that when you tried it. For a start, what's the value if `$Properties['Title']`? was `filter` a declared variable in MySQL when you tried the query? Of what class is `$DB` an instance? Please, provide sufficient info

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem:  `$Properties['Title']` is quoted.  It's more like `SELECT id FROM filter WHERE 'some title' LIKE CONCAT('%', filter, '%')`, which makes quite a bit of sense if `filter` is a column name in the table `filter` and serves as a filter.

Comment: SELECT id FROM tfilter WHERE

Comment: Do you need to be able to use wildcard characters in the `filter` column?

Comment: And before i start assuming too much...there's no `record_count()` method in mysqli or PDO.  If you were to put a `print get_class($DB); exit(0);` before the query, what would show in the page?  If it shows anything besides PDO or mysqli, you're going to have to provide some detail on what DB library you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query needs to be (repace the single quotes around `$Properties['Title']` with backtick):

```
$DB->query("SELECT id FROM filter WHERE `". $Properties['Title'] ."` LIKE CONCAT('%', filter, '%')");
```

Also, you don't need to use the `concat` function to prepend and append `%` character, you can simply use it as follows:

```
$DB->query("SELECT id FROM filter WHERE `". $Properties['Title'] ."` LIKE '%{$filter}%'");
```

Comment: Nopz then i get internal server error. 

The query works, i get one result when running the qxl. But it dosnt DIE in php when it gets a result.
if($DB->record_count() != 0) {
Im thing that maybe need to change, but dont know what to change it to, :(

Comment: The Query works find, there is 1 result on it.. But the it dosnt die on the result in php

Comment: What is $DB, I'm assuming it's one of your implementation.  Can we see your query and record_count definition?

Comment: @Asesinato: If the query worked fine, you wouldn't be asking this question. If the code you provided returned a usable result set, you would be able to get the row count, even if that meant doing a `count($resultSet->fetchAll());`

Comment: Ive put more info in the post above

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem How should i implant that in :
 if($DB->record_count() != 0) {
        $Err = '<b>This cant be uploaded!</b>';
        include(SERVER_ROOT . '/sections/upload/upload.php');
        die();
    }
}

Comment: @Asesinato, Can you post the actual code instead of description so that we can find out why the 500 is thrown.  Also can you explain where `SERVER_ROOT` is defined.  Also check your server log, there should be some information there.

Comment: @Asesinato you should include error checking after querying the database. You assume that the query is working, but the code does not do what you want. Since you rely on the query result, you really must verify that the query was executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

could you not use 
    rowCount() ?

so it should look something like this:

```
$stmt = $DB->query("SELECT id FROM tfilter WHERE '". $Properties['Title'] ."' LIKE CONCAT('%', filter, '%')");
$numrows=$stmt->rowCount();

$error= $stmt->errorInfo();
echo $error[2];

if($numrows) {
$Err = '<b>This cant be uploaded</b>';
include(SERVER_ROOT . '/sections/upload/upload.php');
die();
```

Comment: You mean like this : if($DB->rowCount() != 0) {

Comment: @Asesinato yea, precisely. try it.

Comment: ah sorry, its because you were addressing the PDO object itself, you need address the PDOstatement. so you want $stmt = $DB->query("SELECT id FROM.....); then you want $numrows=$stmt->rowCount(); and then just see if($numrows).... - will be true if 1 row or more

Comment: I need alittle help on do you have want this to look?  if($DB->record_count() != 0) {.... ive added the $stmt = $DB->....

Comment: hmm, ok. the 500 message is notoriously ambiguous. just means something is wrong but doesnt know what. i expect there's something wrong in your "SELECT id.... query. just above if($numrows) - type in: $error= $stmt->errorInfo();
echo $error[2]; - this might give you a more detailed message from the database

Comment: and if you test it with a simple select statement. something like "SELECT id FROM tfilter WHERE id=5" (if there is an id with 5)

Comment: hmm, sounds like there's just some little error in the code somewhere else. maybe you're using a variable for 2 things, or using it for an object and as normal variable. or something's wrong with quotes "'. just keep testing away. welcome to programming.